# Bibliography inside tcolorbox: heading=none conflicts with numbering

Tags: biblatex, tcolorbox

Here's a case study:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,autolang,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@report{foo
        ,author = {Dupont}
    ,month = {08}
    ,title = {\textit{foo}}
    ,institution = {baz}
    ,year = {2019}
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}

@report{bar
    ,author = {Durand}
    ,title = {\textit{bar}}
    ,institution = {qux}
    ,year = {2018}
    ,month = {08}
    ,language={french}
    ,hyphenation={french}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}

This citation has a matching number under Bib:  \cite{foo}, not this one:\cite{bar}. It's totally unacceptable!

\begin{center}

  \vspace*{\fill}

  \begin{tcolorbox}
    [
    width=0.9\textwidth
    ,halign=flush left
    ,arc=0mm
    ,title=Bib
    ,breakable=true
    ]

\printbibliography[heading=none]
%\printbibliography

  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: with header]

[image: w/o header]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put a center environment around the box. Use the center key to center the box:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
    [
    center,
    width=0.9\textwidth
    ,halign=flush left
    ,arc=0mm
    ,title=Bib
    ,breakable=true
    ]
```

[image]